# Flink support for hadoop 3.X

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

I am using Flink 1.13.1 and we plan to injest ftp based sources. Since Flink depends on Hadoop dependencies to support such operations, I need to understand if Flink supports Hadoop 3.X. The documentation doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: Works for me with start-cluster.sh and hadoop 3.3.1 installed on mac with suitable HADOOP_HOME and core-site.xml configurations

Comment: Hadoop3 is supported since Flink 1.11, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11086